# React keyDown event SOMETIMES firing on KeyUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, web-audio-api, keyevent

So right now I've got an incredibly weird phenomenon happening in my React app and I'm not entirely sure how to describe it, but here goes:

I'm building a synthesizer with the Web Audio API and React that responds to `keyDown` events to trigger the beginning of the note and `keyUp` events to trigger the end of the note. Most of the time this works flawlessly. But one key press in every 10-15 results in an additional `keyDown` event firing after the `keyUp` event. I've got a React component that deals with all the event handling and fires off Redux actions depending on the event being handled (`keyUp` or `keyDown`). Additionally, I'm using the `lodash/debounce` method to suppress additional `keyDown` events when the user holds a key.

I'm not wedded to the `lodash/debounce` function, I just need something to suppress the extra `keyDown` events. It's entirely possible I'm not using it properly or that there's an easier solution. I just need answers.

My component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

import { REGISTERED_KEYS } from '../constants/keyboard-constants'

export default class ComputerKeyboard extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)
  }

  handleKeyDown (e) {
    return debounce((event = e) => {
      if (this.props.currentKeys.indexOf(event.keyCode) < 0 && REGISTERED_KEYS.includes(event.keyCode)) {
        this.props.keyDown(event.keyCode)
        this.props.updateGateStartTime({ value: this.props.audioContext.currentTime })
      }
    }, 2)()
  }

  handleKeyUp (e) {
    const isLastKey = this.props.currentKeys.includes(e.keyCode) && this.props.currentKeys.length === 1
    if (isLastKey && this.props.gateStartTime) {
      this.props.updateGateStartTime({ value: null })
    }
    if (this.props.currentKeys.includes(e.keyCode) && REGISTERED_KEYS.includes(e.keyCode)) {
      this.props.keyUp(e.keyCode)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown)
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp)
  }

  render () {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's see the JSX.

Comment: @RandyCasburn There is no JSX for this component. It just renders `null` and puts the eventListeners on the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

It was the `debounce`. Once I removed that, I never saw the error again. I was trying to get fancy but didn't understand the difference between throttling and debouncing. As per this [article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/):

> Throttling enforces a maximum number of times a function can be called over time. As in "execute this function at most once every 100 milliseconds."

and

> Debouncing enforces that a function not be called again until a certain amount of time has passed without it being called. As in "execute this function only if 100 milliseconds have passed without it being called."

My thought is that I likely want to be throttling and that by debouncing, I was allowing the last call of the function to be let through because the amount of time between calls was short enough that occasionally, upon release, the debounce let an event through that it should not have. Additionally, because the key was no longer depressed and registered as such, the the fail safe logic built into the `handleKeyDown` was no longer adequate because it presupposes that there are actually keys engaged.